# discord py bot has no attribute slash_command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

That is all of the imports I have, it works on my pc however when I tried to run it on my pi4 I got the error saying no attribute slash_command, I installed all the packages I thought I needed which was, py-cord, discord.py. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: Imports]
[image: error]
[image: bot line]

Comment: Start by [searching the API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=slash_command)

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out I had to install `py-cord` through this command:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Pycord-Development/pycord
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't `commands.Bot`, it's `discord.Bot`

Try this:

```
bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)

bot.slash_command(description="Test")
async def test(ctx):
    ctx.respond("This is a test!")
```

`commands.Bot` doesn't support slash commands.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'